# ¿Como obtener valor de un select de html en js mediante el DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, html-select

bueno el problema que tengo es que quiero hacer algo muy simple y es que quiero realizar una operación matemática dependiendo el tipo de operación que se halla seleccionado (este se hace mediante el tipo ) pero no se como acceder mediante el DOM para que poder hacer dicha operación este es el código que tengo por ahora

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input id="numero1" type="text" name="">
        <input id="numero2" type="text" name="">
        <select id="operaciones">
            <option id="suma" value="sumaa">Suma</option>
            <option id="multiplicacion" value="multiplicaionn">multiplicacion</option>
            <option id="divicion" value="divicionn">Divicion</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="" value="calcular" onclick="operacion()">

    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function operacion(){
    var numero1=document.getElementById("numero1");
    var numero1=parseFloat("numero1");
    var numero2=document.getElementById("numero2");
    var numero1=parseFloat("numero1");

    var operation = document.getElementById("operaciones").value;
    if (operation=="suma" ){
         /*Codigo de la operacion de la suma aqui*/
    }
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Si necesitan mas información me la hacen saber. Muchas gracias**

Answer (score 1):

El valor del selector lo obtienes bien tal como tienes:

```
var operation = document.getElementById("operaciones").value;
```

Pero en tu ejemplo su valor sería `"sumaa"` ya que así es en `value` del  `<option>`

Tienes que ser más cuidadoso en la redacción, tanto de las preguntas como del código ;) 
revísalo porque tienes otros errores que impiden el buen funcionamiento.

Te dejo el código corregido para que te sirva de referencia:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input id="numero1" type="text" name="">
        <input id="numero2" type="text" name="">
        <select id="operaciones">
            <option id="suma" value="suma">Suma</option>
            <option id="multiplicacion" value="multiplicaion">multiplicacion</option>
            <option id="divicion" value="divicion">Divicion</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="" value="calcular" onclick="operacion()">

    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function operacion(){

    var numero1=document.getElementById("numero1").value;
    numero1=parseFloat(numero1);
    var numero2=document.getElementById("numero2").value;
    numero2=parseFloat(numero2);

    var operation = document.getElementById("operaciones").value;
    if (operation=="suma" ){
         /*Codigo de la operacion de la suma aqui*/
      alert(operation+': '+(numero1+numero2) );
    }
    if (operation=="multiplicacion" ){
         /*Codigo de la operacion de la multiplicacion aqui*/
      alert(operation+': '+(numero1*numero2) );
    }    
    if (operation=="divicion" ){
         /*Codigo de la operacion de la divicion aqui*/
      alert(operation+': '+(numero1/numero2) );
    }       
      return false;
}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes comprobarlo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/ngmwo2ac/

Answer (score 0):

Hola solo debes elegir el indice seleccionado

```
var select = document.getElementById("operaciones");
var selectedOperation = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

referencia de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas jquery es más sencillo, simplemente.

```
var operacion = $('#operaciones').val();
```